# Ternary operators and PHP includes

Tags: php, include, ternary-operator

i'm trying to use ternary operator to check files validity  before including them instead of if statements; but i can't get it to function for some reason the page returns blank. What did i miss ?

```
(is_file('connect.php')) ? include 'connect.php' : echo "erreur de chargement"; 
(is_file('header.html')) ? include 'header.html' : echo "erreur de chargement";
(is_file('nav.html')) ? include 'nav.html' : echo "erreur de chargement";
(is_file('table.html')) ? include 'table.html' : echo "erreur de chargement";
(is_file('footer.html')) ? include 'footer.html' : echo "erreur de chargement";
```

Comment: Enable error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php what does that throw back?

Comment: `echo` is a statement, not an expression. Any particular reason you're not simply using `require`?

Comment: I dunno i just got into the habit of testing every files etc before inserting them or using them in functions so i can trouble shoot more easily later on if some parts of my code do not work because something is missing, or if made a typo in copying the file name etc.

But you guys are right i'm probly over doing it for no reason in this case. 

And indeed the "echo" part was the issue here. 

So out of curiosity if you'd want to achieve the result i was looking for when the file doesn't exist, you'd have to use an if/else statement and not this operator then ?

Comment: @gountaa, have you found a suitable solution in any of those # answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternaries are used to create strings usually, so this won't work because you are trying to use an expression, which is not supported by the ternary.

If you absolutely want to avoid [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) for some reason, it may be better to make an array of files that you require to be included, and loop through them.

```
$require = [
    'connect.php', 
    'header.html'
    //... etc
];

foreach($require as $file) {
    if(is_file($file)) {

        //if file exists, include and continue to next requirement
        include $file;
        continue;
    }

    //if this code is reached, the file does not exist.
    echo "erreur de chargement $file";
    //or die("erreur de chargement $file"); if you want the page to stop executing on failure
}
```

This is also nice because you can trivially add new requirements, or even create a database of requirements that is automatically put into this array.

However, it would definitely be easier and more recommended to just use [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot this answered all my questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to use ternary operator like that. You can not include as true result and echo as false result of ternary operator. Write it with `if` instead:

```
if (is_file('connect.php')) include 'connect.php' else echo "erreur de chargement"; 
if (is_file('header.html')) include 'header.html' else echo "erreur de chargement";
if (is_file('nav.html')) include 'nav.html' else echo "erreur de chargement";
if (is_file('table.html')) include 'table.html' else echo "erreur de chargement";
if (is_file('footer.html')) include 'footer.html' else echo "erreur de chargement";
```

**Why you see blank page?**

It's because you set error reporting off. use this at very first line of your code to enabling error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is build in feature in PHP: `include` and `require` both in variants with `_once` that does the job for you without need of such ternary conditioning.

[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

[require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.

Very simplified: if `include` or include_once does not find the file then PHP generates  E_WARNING only and the script continues.

However if `require` or require_once does not find the file then PHP generates a FATAL error and terminate the script.

Use it instead of any kind of conditions even ternary ones.